# spring webservice returns get appended to url

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a simple web services as shown below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api")
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello() {
        System.out.println("this test is done ");
        return "this is test url";
    }
}
```

my web.xml file goes like this

```
<servlet-name>pa</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>pa</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

now whern i hit this URL:`http://localhost:8556/pa/api`
it shows some thing like this

```
HTTP Status 404 - /pa/this is test url

type Status report

message /pa/this is test url

description The requested resource (/pa/this is test url) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
```

ie. the return string gets appended to url.

here is my spring_context.xml

```
<bean id="log4jInitialization" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:logger/log4j.properties</value>
            <!-- log4j.refresh.interval -->
            <value>5000</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Not just the answer can you please explain me what is happning inside the container and why is it happning.
Tell me if any thing is required.
Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the the reason why its happning ...
it goes like this:

the thing is,

```
All controllers in the Spring Web MVC framework return a ModelAndView instance. 
Views in Spring are addressed by a view name and are resolved by a view resolver.
```

so what ever is returned, act as a view and hence appended to URL
to resolve this i Use `@ResponceBody`, as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api")
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponceBody String hello() {
        System.out.println("this test is done ");
        return "this is test url";
    }
}
```

**Now what @ResponceBody do**:
It indicates that the HTTP message converter mechanism should take over and transform the returned object into whatever form that the client needs. This will tell spring to look into HTTP Accept header and choose appropriate converter. If we supply Accept header with application/json value then JSON MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter converter will be invoked.

Tell me if further info is required.

Comment: Were you not satisfied with the answer I gave you? Your first quote does not apply to your situation. You are neither returning a `ModelAndView` not does that rule apply to Spring 3+.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis...  you told me the working of container that why it appends the return value with parameter, but you didnt tell me the solution for that.
But then i truly appriciate your answer...
thanks.

Comment: Solution to what? Your question doesn't say anything about how to achieve different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The [Spring MVC documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) explains this in the `Supported method return types` section

> The following are the supported return types:
>
> [...]
>
> - A String value that is interpreted as the logical view name, with the
>     model implicitly determined through command objects and
>     @ModelAttribute annotated reference data accessor methods.

Your method returns a `String`, so its value is therefore interpreted as a view name. You probably have declared an `InternalResourceViewResolver` in your context which takes the view name and tries to resolve an `InternalResourceView`. This is done by using `HttpServletRequest#getRequestDispatcher()` with the view name (prefixed and suffixed as configured).

Read the documentation [on resolving views.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver)

Comment: sotitios i havent use any view resolver i will put the code for it aswell.

Comment: @MayurGupta Put your full context.